# What is the alternative for this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization

Here is my query below. Which takes 4 minutes to run in sql server and through .net code it is taking more than 1 hour. Kindly suggest alternate solution for this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(
        CASE
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(URL), 1) = 1)
                THEN LEFT(URL, LEN(URL) - 1)
            ELSE URL
        END, 'http://', ''), 'www.', '') AS URL,
    NULL AS [source],
    REPLACE(REPLACE(
        CASE
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TargetURL), 1) = 1)
                THEN LEFT(TargetURL, LEN(TargetURL) - 1)
            ELSE TargetURL
        END, 'http://', ''), 'www.', '') AS TargetURL,
    NULL AS [target],
    PageAuthority AS Authority,
    1 AS [isInternal]
FROM [Internal](nolock)
WHERE Domain_ID = 2
    AND NoofDomainsLinkingtothisPage > 1
    AND REPLACE(REPLACE(
        CASE
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(URL), 1) = 1)
                THEN LEFT(URL, LEN(URL) - 1)
            ELSE URL
        END, 'http://', ''), 'www.', '')
            IN (SELECT DISTINCT URL FROM #tempCalAuthTable11(NOLOCK))--864

    AND REPLACE(REPLACE(
        CASE
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TargetURL), 1) = 1)
                THEN LEFT(TargetURL, LEN(TargetURL) - 1)
            ELSE TargetURL
        END, 'http://', ''), 'www.', '')
            IN (SELECT DISTINCT URL FROM #tempCalAuthTable11(NOLOCK))
```

Here is the execution Plan Details.

[image]

Comment: Add execution plan. Without that, we can just speculate.

Comment: also provide some sample data to work out

Comment: Add `UNIQUE` index for `#tempCalAuthTable11` + `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for query

Comment: Thanks Devart. It works for me.

Comment: @Musakkhir Sayyed you are welcome ;)

Comment: Read an article [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: Using nolock means it is ok to have missing and duplicate rows in the result and also incorrect and corrupted data in the result. I wonder what You are going to use this for.